# Having trouble making background scroll infinitely

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a game with sprite kit and objective c. Currently I am trying to make my background scroll infinitely. I cannot seem to make this work. Here is my code:

SKAction method

```
-(void) setUpActions {
SKAction* move = [SKAction moveByX:-landscape.frame.size.width * 2 y:0 duration:2.0];
SKAction* reset = [SKAction moveByX:landscape.frame.size.width * 2 y:0 duration:0.0];
SKAction* moveInfinitely = [SKAction sequence:@[move, reset]];


//background and log Moving Actions
moveOver = [SKAction repeatActionForever:moveInfinitely];
}
```

SKAction calling method

```
-(void) runTheAction {
[landscape runAction:moveOver];
}
```

When I run the app nothing shows up on my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two background sprites.

```
// create 2 background sprites
    bg1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bg1"];
    bg1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    bg1.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
     [self addChild:bg1];

    bg2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bg2"];
    bg2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg1.size.width-1, 0);
     [self addChild:bg2];
```

Then in update method:

```
bg1.position = CGPointMake(bg1.position.x-4, bg1.position.y);
bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg2.position.x-4, bg2.position.y);

if (bg1.position.x < -bg1.size.width){
    bg1.position = CGPointMake(bg2.position.x + bg2.size.width, bg1.position.y);
}

if (bg2.position.x < -bg2.size.width) {
    bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg1.position.x + bg1.size.width, bg2.position.y);
}
```

This should be pretty straightforward

Comment: Thank You. How would I change it so that it could move left instead. I tried instead of subtracting when setting the positions to adding when setting them. That didn't work